# How to verify kerberos token?

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, spnego, gssapi

so it's me again with some AD and Kerberos problems.

Alright cool, I get a kerberos token from the WWW-Authenticate header. Now I want to verify this token against an AD but I don't know how.

I found some stuff from GSSAPI but didn't see a function or method to take an byte[] as Kerberos token or any other way.

I am running an Java EE web application.

What can I do with this token to get the user and especially an "this token and user are legit" from the AD?

EDIT:

So as said in the comments I'm really close to being able to perform SSO. So I will update you guys with what I have.

I got a server named ping01 and my local machine. Running on a Tomcat as the user mgmt I have my application. So I did all this:

Created the SPN HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN at user mgmt.

krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
permitted_enctypes   = aes256-cts rc4-hmac des3-cbc-sha1 des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc
default_realm = COOL.DOMAIN
kdc_timesync = 1
ccache_type = 5
forwardable = true
proxiable = true

[realms]
COOL.DOMAIN = {
kdc = kdc.cool.domain
admin_server = COOL.DOMAIN
default_domain = COOL.DOMAIN
}

[domain_realm]
cool.domain = COOL.DOMAIN
ping01 = COOL.DOMAIN



[login]
krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false
```

Also I have this code:

```
 /**
   * Gets the jaas krb 5 ticket cfg.
   *
   * @param principal the principal
   * @param realm the realm
   * @param keyTab the key tab
   * @return the jaas krb 5 ticket cfg
   */
  private static Configuration getJaasKrb5TicketCfg( final String principal, final String realm, final File keyTab )
  {
    return new Configuration()
    {
      @Override
      public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry( String name )
      {
        Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
        options.put( "principal", principal );
        options.put( "realm", realm );
        options.put( "doNotPrompt", "true" );
        options.put( "useKeyTab", "true" );
        options.put( "keyTab", keyTab.getAbsolutePath() );
        options.put( "storeKey", "true" );
        options.put( "isInitiator", "false" );

        return new AppConfigurationEntry[] {
            new AppConfigurationEntry( "com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule", LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, options ) };
      }
    };
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public boolean isTicketValid( String spn, byte[] ticket )
  {
    LoginContext ctx = null;
    try
    {
      /** define the principal who will validate the ticket */
      Principal principal = new KerberosPrincipal( spn, KerberosPrincipal.KRB_NT_SRV_INST );
      Set<Principal> principals = new HashSet<>();
      principals.add( principal );

      /** define the subject to execute our secure action as */
      Subject subject = new Subject( false, principals, new HashSet<>(), new HashSet<>() );

      /** login the subject */
      /**
       * TODO: Find the correct way to use the commented out version!
       */
      // ctx = new LoginContext( "http_ping01_domain", subject );
      ctx = new LoginContext( "doesn't matter", subject, null,
          getJaasKrb5TicketCfg( "HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN", "COOL.DOMAIN",
              new File( "http_ping01_test.ktab" ) ) );
      ctx.login();

      /** create a validator for the ticket and execute it */
      SingleSignOnImpl validateAction = new SingleSignOnImpl( ticket, spn, log );
      String username = Subject.doAs( subject, validateAction );
      log.info( "Validated service ticket for user " + username + " to access service " + spn );
      return true;
    }
    catch ( PrivilegedActionException e )
    {
      /**
       * Error reasons for this Exception: - Incorrect Kerberos Mechanism - Incorrect Token received
       * - Incorrect keytab
       */
      log.error( "Invalid ticket for " + spn + ": " + e );
    }
    catch ( LoginException e )
    {
      /**
       * Error reasons for this Exception: - False krb5.conf (can't reach KDC) - incorrect SPN -
       * False login.conf
       */
      log.error( "Error creating validation LoginContext for " + spn + ": " + e );
    }
    finally
    {
      try
      {
        if ( ctx != null )
        {
          ctx.logout();
        }
      }
      catch ( LoginException e )
      {
        log.error( "" + e );
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

In addition to this I have the privilegedAction in a seperate class:

```
public class SingleSignOnImpl implements PrivilegedExceptionAction<String>
{

  /** The ticket from the client. */
  private final byte[] ticket;

  /** The Service principal name (SPN). */
  private final String spn;

  /** The log. */
  private Log log;

  /**
   * Inits the.
   *
   * @param log the log
   */
  @Inject
  public void init( Log log )
  {
    this.log = log;
  }

  /**
   * Instantiates a new single sign on impl.
   *
   * @param ticket the ticket
   * @param spn the spn
   */
  public SingleSignOnImpl( byte[] ticket, String spn, Log log )
  {
    this.ticket = ticket;
    this.spn = spn;
    this.log = log;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public String run() throws Exception
  {
    /**
     * Kerberos V5 Mechanism or SPNEGO required. the Legacy mechanism is NOT supported. SPNEGO
     * (1.3.6.1.5.5.2); Kerberos V5 (1.2.840.113554.1.2.2)
     */
    final Oid spnegoOid = new Oid( "1.3.6.1.5.5.2" );

    GSSManager gssmgr = GSSManager.getInstance();

    /** tell the GSSManager the Kerberos name of the service */
    GSSName serviceName = gssmgr.createName( this.spn, GSSName.NT_USER_NAME );

    /**
     * get the service's credentials. note that this run() method was called by Subject.doAs(), so
     * the service's credentials are already available in the Subject
     */
    GSSCredential serviceCredentials = gssmgr.createCredential( serviceName, GSSCredential.INDEFINITE_LIFETIME, spnegoOid,
        GSSCredential.ACCEPT_ONLY );

    /** create a security context for decrypting the service ticket */
    GSSContext gssContext = gssmgr.createContext( serviceCredentials );

    /** decrypt the service ticket */
    log.info( "Entering accpetSecContext..." );
    gssContext.acceptSecContext( this.ticket, 0, this.ticket.length );

    /**
     * get the client name from the decrypted service ticket note that Active Directory created the
     * service ticket, so we can trust it
     */
    String clientName = gssContext.getSrcName().toString();
    log.info( "request from Client {0}", clientName );

    /** clean up the context. This is very important */
    gssContext.dispose();

    return clientName;
  }

}
```

My log spits out this:

```
AUTHTOKEN: YIIG2gYGKw......
2016-11-08 14:52:34,269 INFO Entering accpetSecContext...
2016-11-08 14:52:34,269 ERROR Invalid ticket for HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
2016-11-08 14:52:34,269 INFO VALID: false
```

But the good news is that I get a Kerberos token. he enters the Context and can decrypt it. When using **klist** in cmd I even see a cached ticket for my service. as shown here: [directUpload](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161108/2t78o599.png)

Active Directory and KDC runs smoothly and no error or warning is shown when I request the ticket to access the service.

The byte[] with the token is taken from the httprequest from the header and decoded from string to byte[] with Base64.getMimeDecoder.decode();

does anybody see my mistake? After rebooting and purging the ticket cache I still get the message.

EDIT 2:

I digged around more and tried around with ktab and kinit. When trying to get a ticket for the SPN with kinit I run into this:

```
kinit -J-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -k -t http_ping01.ktab HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN

>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\Nico.DOMAIN\XXXX_Nico
Principal is HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN

>>> Kinit using keytab
>>> Kinit keytab file name: http_ping01.ktab
Java config name: null

LSA: Found Ticket
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found PrincipalName
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found EncryptionKey
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found TicketFlags
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found KerberosTime
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found String
LSA: Made NewWeakGlobalRef
LSA: Found DerValue constructor
LSA: Found Ticket constructor
LSA: Found PrincipalName constructor
LSA: Found EncryptionKey constructor
LSA: Found TicketFlags constructor
LSA: Found KerberosTime constructor
LSA: Finished OnLoad processing

Native config name: C:\Windows\krb5.ini
Loaded from native config
>>> Kinit realm name is COOL.DOMAIN
>>> Creating KrbAsReq
>>> KrbKdcReq local addresses for my_computer are:

[My addresses]

>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01.cool.domain
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 98; type: 18

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01.cool.domain
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 82; type: 17

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01.cool.domain
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 82; type: 23

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01.cool.domain
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 90; type: 16

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 80; type: 18

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 64; type: 17

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 64; type: 23

>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): COOL.DOMAIN
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): HTTP
>>> KeyTabInputStream, readName(): ping01
>>> KeyTab: load() entry length: 72; type: 16

Looking for keys for: HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN
Added key: 16version: 2
Added key: 23version: 2
Added key: 17version: 2
Added key: 18version: 2
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 18 17 23 16.

>>> KrbAsReq creating message
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=KDC.cool.domain UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=270
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=KDC.cool.domain UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=270
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=106
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove KDC.cool.domain
>>> KDCRep: init() encoding tag is 126 req type is 11

>>>KRBError:
         sTime is Wed Nov 09 10:54:46 CET 2016 1478685286000
         suSec is 578393
         error code is 6
         error Message is Client not found in Kerberos database
         sname is ActiveDirectory/COOL.DOMAIN@COOL.DOMAIN
         msgType is 30
Exception: krb_error 6 Client not found in Kerberos database (6) Client not found in Kerberos database

KrbException: Client not found in Kerberos database (6)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:76)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:316)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.<init>(Kinit.java:219)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.main(Kinit.java:113)
Caused by: KrbException: Identifier doesn't match expected value (906)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.KDCRep.init(KDCRep.java:140)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.init(ASRep.java:64)
        at sun.security.krb5.internal.ASRep.<init>(ASRep.java:59)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(KrbAsRep.java:60)
        ... 4 more
```

so I looked at the object ping01 in our active directory. It already got a bunch of servicePrincipalName attributes:

> servicePrincipalName: someService/PING01.cool.domain
>
> servicePrincipalName: someService/PING01
>
> servicePrincipalName: anotherService/PING01.cool.domain
>
> servicePrincipalName: anotherService/PING01
>
> servicePrincipalName: HOST/PING01.cool.domain
>
> servicePrincipalName: HOST/PING01

using `setspn -l mgmt` outputs the SPN I created though. Just not visible in the ldapBrowser at all.

I am not sure if the object Ping01 (objectClass=computer) has a password or not, have to wait for an answer of the sys admin.

EDIT 3:
I figured out it must be some kind of SPN problem or at least an AD problem.
From **EDIT 2:** you can see that even the windows native tool **kinit** can't perform the authentication since the kdc is sending the message he doesn't know the user. Why he states to the SPN as user is unclear to me but turning on more debug options gave me this output:

```
YIIG2gYGKwYBBQUCoIIGzjCCBsqgMDAuBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCqKCBpQEggaQYIIGjAYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBuggZ7MIIGd6ADAgEFoQMCAQ6iBwMFACAAAACjggUGYYIFAjCCBP6gAwIBBaETGxFGRUxURU5HUk9VUC5MT0NBTKIrMCmgAwIBAqEiMCAbBEhUVFAbGHBpbmcwMS5mZWx0ZW5ncm91cC5sb2NhbKOCBLMwggSvoAMCAR[...]
INFO [stdout] Debug is true storeKey true useTicketCache false useKeyTab true doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false KeyTab is C:\path\to\http_ping01_test.ktab refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
INFO [stdout] principal is HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN
INFO [stdout] Will use keytab
INFO [stdout] Commit Succeeded
INFO [stdout] Found KeyTab C:\path\to\http_ping01_test.ktab for HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN
INFO Entering accpetSecContext...
INFO [stdout] Entered SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
INFO [stdout] SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: receiving token = a0 82 06 ce 30 82 06 ca a0 30 30 2e 06 09 2a 86 48 82 f7 12 01 02 02 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 06 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 1e 06 0a 2b 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 0a a2 82 06 94 04 82 06 90 60 82 06 8c 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 12 01 02 02 01 00 6e 82 06 7b 30 82 06 77 a0 03 02 01 05 a1 03 02 01 0e a2 07 03 05 00 20 00 00 00 a3 82 05 06 61 82 05 02 30 82 04 fe a0 03 02 01 05 a1 13 1b 11 46 45 4c 54 45 4e 47 52 4f 55 50 2e 4c 4f 43 41 4c a2 2b 30 29 a0 03 02 01 02 a1 22 30 20 1b 04 48 54 54 50 1b 18 70 69 6e 67 30 31 2e 66 65 6c 74 65 6e 67 72 6f 75 70 2e 6c 6f 63 61 6c a3 82 04 b3 30 82 04 af a0 03 02 01 12 a1 03 02 01 0f a2 82 04 a1 04 82 04 9d e6 c0 24 8d 0d 24 8e e1 4e e8 0d 4e 4d 5b 7e 06 58 d9 f2 04 a6 99 55 e2 61 67 99 60 ec 47 42 7d 60 64 4d bc f7 ef 99 5b f0 3e b8 2f 9a ff 2d 83 19 6d f1 5f ac 44 08 f3 50 d5 c9 53 af 6f d9 d6 81 c1 d7 24 03 6a 9d b4 9d 56 53 93 b3 1d 07 15 77 c5 fb 25 0f bc f8 97 8f 97 0c 26 ae 52 d0 fc f3 72 98 9c 79 4b af e2 88 3b a6 2b 1b 03 b0 93 b6 6a dd b3 c6 f8 c2 01 eb a4 1b 8a 64 74 cb 5b f4 4b 5c d7 02 48 1d 0d 5e 29 3d 2b 82 c5 79 a1 7a e1 4c 92 32 7c 6b f6 56 ff e1 3a 3f b7 ce 0c 92 f8 ae ce 03 f2 f5 18 53 5c 5b 08 07 60 d7 c0 38 7d d0 f5 fa 2b 63 97 61 75 86 b6 95 44 49 76 93 38 88 82 7f 90 07 d7 3d c9 bd c6 c7 b3 af 47 55 cc b0 1a cd 2a e8 4e d0 b9 42 9e 65 3e aa 88 ac b5 25 45 39 20 0f 3c 50 ed 2d 1a f5 24 04 5a 15 99 c9 2e c1 c6 40 4e 26 ea f2 c6 a9 bd 61 24 fc d4 25 6e ed c2 40 3a d6 18 9b 53 ac 4d a1 61 d2 12 aa 99 e1 90 6e 22 c9 14 82 49 78 43 ab 83 a1 60 a3 d0 1d 33 24 11 41 07 4d bb 9c 0e 38 e1 3c 86 6a 62 bc 2f 7c 47 34 b7 42 3e 28 2e 9b 26 66 a1 e8 61 5f 00 61 8a b9 2b 5b 9e b2 aa 1a 4d e7 4e d2 6d 52 e1 25 c4 89 ea 6e 85 1c 1a 56 e0 d9 a2 be 9f 7c ee 89 55 b8 39 cf b9 92 77 33 2d fa 64 29 50 38 2d 6d d7 9d be be 3c e2 04 4c 5c 3e 3b d1 09 39 08 bd 75 5b 9f 6a 89 32 f8 b2 a9 c7 a3 a1 de ca ea fd 62 18 7d df 5e 50 b5 8e 48 71 ec 66 70 ff 0e 1c 40 2a ad 9e f4 c4 15 45 ca 1b 15 b8 0e 30 76 76 9b 81 39 5b 94 c4 0a ec e0 a7 b4 ec 32 9a 4a 9d 74 86 a3 81 5a 91 8c 51 e1 5a f1 b8 44 fa 9d cc 16 34 c5 99 fb 7b 33 bc 06 99 51 9e ec 19 60 88  [...]
INFO [stdout] SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
INFO [stdout] SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
INFO [stdout] SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
INFO [stdout] SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mechanism Oid = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
INFO [stdout] SpNegoToken NegTokenInit: reading Mech Token
INFO [stdout] SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: received token of type = SPNEGO NegTokenInit
INFO [stdout] SpNegoContext: negotiated mechanism = 1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
INFO [stdout] SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext: negotiated mech adjusted to 1.2.840.48018.1.2.2
INFO [stdout] Entered Krb5Context.acceptSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
INFO [stdout] Looking for keys for: HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN
INFO [stdout] Added key: 16version: 2
INFO [stdout] Added key: 23version: 2
INFO [stdout] Added key: 17version: 2
INFO [stdout] Added key: 18version: 2
INFO [stdout] >>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes256CtsHmacSha1EType
ERROR Invalid ticket for HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: GSSException: Failure unspecified at GSS-API level (Mechanism level: Checksum failed)
INFO [stdout] [Krb5LoginModule]: Entering logout
INFO [stdout] [Krb5LoginModule]: logged out Subject
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments to the answer from Todd, when I write **DOMAIN** I mean the real domain which from now on will be named **cool.domain** just for examplary purpose. Hope this helps to get a hold of what my problem might be. I am stuck on this for quite some time now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual examination process of the security token - containing the Kerberos ticket - takes place on your application server - it never contacts AD.   GSSAPI security functions handle this - you don't code for that.  You can expose the token (looks like a random string of letters) but only the keytab can de-crypt that.  When you (as an application server) get a Kerberos ticket (the authentication token) from a user you know that user is legit - users don't get a ticket in the first place unless their identity has already been proven to AD - that's how Kerberos works.  Check out this URL for more information:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html

Some new observations I made based on your edited question:

1. The SPN is wrong.  Format you provided "SPN HTTP/ping01.domain@DOMAIN" is missing two labels, one in the host part in the middle and one in the realm part at the end.  Should be like "HTTP/ping01.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM" if you're going to use it like that.  With properly functioning DNS in place and krb5.conf properly configured, SPN can actually be like this: "HTTP/ping01.domain.com".

Add new SPN like this:

setspn -S HTTP/ping01.domain.com domain\account

(setspn -S looks for duplicates before adding, while setspn -A does now)

2. There are mistakes in krb5.conf.  You have:

   default_realm = DOMAIN

should be:

```
default_realm = DOMAIN.COM
```

Further down in krb5.conf, under [realms] and {domain_realm] all name references need to be fully-qualified as well.

3. This applies to the same references within your code block as well, I noticed names missing labels in there such as this one:

   getJaasKrb5TicketCfg( "HTTP/ping01.domain@DOMAIN", "DOMAIN",

should be:

```
getJaasKrb5TicketCfg( "HTTP/ping01.domain.com@DOMAIN.COM", "DOMAIN.COM",
```

Kerberos is extremely reliant upon DNS, all name references should be fully-qualified inside all code and krb5.conf.

Comment: Ok good to know so I need to use GSSAPI somehow to use the token. I know that the kerberos token is legit and means the system contacting me is legit. I am trying to perform single sign on so he browses to my website and then he doesn't have to enter any username and password. So I need to kind of make a second step after receveing the token that I know it's not faked and extract the username out of there to then log in the user. Well I will look into GSSAPI more detailed then I guess. Thanks :)

Comment: This example has a screenshot showing the username extracted from the Kerberos ticket:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/idm/weblogic-sso-kerberos-1619890.html

Comment: I need to thank you Mister. After digging deep into the kerberos and gss-api I finally am so close to being done. So I configured a krb5.ini, a keytab and a configuration that the logincontext can use and implemented a priviligedAction to accept and extract the token. Now the last error I have is the Checksum failed but I can already see where that comes from and will get that one fixed too. Accepted as answer and +1 for the hint.

Comment: @Nico - yes, sounds like you're really close.  For the "Checksum failed" message, I've seen that before, run the command 'klist purge' to clear your Kerberos cache or simply reboot the client machine, and then try to access the Kerberos-protected resource again, that should do it.

Comment: I updated my question with a lot more informations. Maybe you can help me now with my problem. This is actually harder than thought.

Comment: I edited my answer since you added more to your question.

Comment: Ok maybe I edited my source code too much. Actually I registered everything with the actual domain which let's just say examplary is **cool.domain** and everywhere were I wrote DOMAIN, I really meant COOL.DOMAIN since our domain doesn't end with .com but something different internally. Performing a nslookup results in **ping01.cool.domain** too.

Comment: You've done too much "editing" here to actually understand what's going on.  I'm sorry, but I cannot help you further.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but I have disclosure to follow. Still thank you for your help so far. It really helped me a lot to get this far.

Answer (score 4):

So I got this working. 
The problem was that the created SPN was not recognized or at least resolved incorrectly. Due to this I got an Checksum error when trying to decrypt the key.

After some help from the technet community we got that right.

I created the SPN like this:

```
setspn -a HTTP/ping01.cool.domain@COOL.DOMAIN mgmt
```

but that was incorrect and the correct form of setting the SPN is:

```
setspn -a HTTP/ping01.cool.domain domain\mgmt
```

This little and simple difference did all the magic for my service to work.

Hope this can help someone some day.

Comment: Thanks for getting back Nico.  I noted to create the SPN without the @KerberosRealm notation, and I'm glad you came back to this thread to verify it.  In the future, suggest also to use "-s" rather than "-a", for the reasons that I mentioned...  :-)